# Exclude sites not in the Android app from the intent filter

Tags: feature-request, android-app

Whenever going to Area51 or chat on Chrome for Android, an application chooser opens because the app has an intent filter for all Stack Exchange websites. However, these sites cannot be opened in the app, so it is an annoying and pointless dialog. Can this intent filter exclude all sites that can't be opened by the Android app?